# Running Halo CE on mac, getting "Gathering Exception Data" error. Help?

Tags: macos, wine, halo-combat-evolved

I got Halo CE (not custom edition) for PC. I ran it through wineskin wrapper (WS9Wine1.9.2) and use the setup.exe.

Once I ran it, it gave me a missing pidgen.dll file error. I searched online and found that if I copied the mfc42.dll file into the system32 file I could fix this.

Once I did that, it ran through setup, installed fine. HOWEVER once I get to the main screen, it crashes giving a "Gathering Exception Data" prompt, from which I can find several pages of details I don't understand. I can give pertinent details from there if necessary, but am not overly familiar with wineskin/etc.

I've searched far and wide, but the only fixes I've found (few) were for Ubuntu wineskin, or general issues. Nothing that could help me.

I've been working on this for a while, and I just want to play the darn game. Can anyone help me fix this (hopefully) last issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with wineskin, but I do know that porting games manually usually ends up a hassle, and a lot of problems in general. Since its as old as it is (halo), I think you would honestly have less trouble just running windows in a virtual machine, and installing halo on that. Your Mac should have the resources to play a game from 2001 in a virtual machine. Other than that, your best bet would to find a wineskin or Mac forum, and post a topic with your problem, and your error log attached. There are people with a LOT of wineskin and porting experience in general, but I don't know about here.